# Ionic3 with AngularFire2 process observable into Object array

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angularfire2

I am having some problems moving my returned data from AngularFire2 into data structures within my code.  The basics of simply getting a list of objects works for me, but I am trying to process a simpler list into an array.

My data in Firebase (V4.10.1, AngularFire2 V5.0.0-rc.6) is in

```
/teams/
    ABC:Team Name A
    DEF:Team Name B
```

My data is in the list as : format.  I want to process this return data into a typescript array `teamName['ABC'] = 'Team Name A'`.

I am able to get the data and place it in the console.log() using: `this.AfDb.list(Location).snapshotChanges().subscribe(console.log);`

I have the problem when I try to process the data:

```
private Data_:{};

constructor(AfDb:AngularFirebaseDatabase) {
    const AfData:Observable<{}> = this.AfDb.list(Location).snapshotChanges();
    AfData.subscribe(list => {
            list.forEach(OneRec => {
                this.Data_[OneRec.key] = OneRec.payload.val();
            });
        });
}
```

I get an error that my Key value [OneRec.key].
`core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'ABC' of undefined.`

I have tried using Data_:any; without success as well.  I have recently turned on the TSLint functions in Ionic which is why I am trying to typedef all variables.

Answer (score 1):

You've not initialized `Data_` only set the type, thus it is undefined.

`private Data_ = {};`

Comment: True, but I still do not get an array of what I want. I am looking to populate the data into an array to use it with the key being the data from AngularFire2 and then the content, the results from AngularFire2.